# IE6 <input type='text' /> width issue

Tags: css

I have an annoying IE6 layout bug

This screenshot shows the problem:

[image]

**Problem: Text inputs** i.e. `<input type='text' />` are wrong size.

The text inputs are a bit wonky.  They are supposed to be 248px wide (like the textarea) and on the same horizontal level as their labels. All other browsers appear to obey the following code but our friend IE6 doesn't

```
.simple_form input[type='text'],.simple_form input[type='email'],.simple_form textarea
  {
    width:240px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:3px
  }
```

I dunno what I'm doing wrong here and it's driving me nuts. The page in question is [here](http://lambhillstables.org/contacts/new). The inputs are significantly wider than 248px in IE6. Does IE6 have a problem understanding `input[type='text']` when used in CSS?

Can post more code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE6 doesn't support the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Attribute_selectors) in CSS.

You will to select those elements using an IE6 compatible way, such as classes.

Comment: Who cares about IE6..... ya ya I know I know clients are using it but yeah.... IT SUCKS... Alex is right you need a fallback option for the selectors you have for them to work in IE6, perhaps a class for the inputs?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answers, also remember to keep said css selector in a separate selector. So for example,

```
input[type="text"], input.text {
  color: red;
}
```

This will be completely ignored by IE6. But...

```
input[type="text"] {
  color: red;
} 
input.text {
  color: red;
}
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

IE6 does not support CSS attribute selectors. Try a selector like the following instead:

```
.simple_form input.text {
  ...
}
```

In addition, remember the differences in the [box model for IE6](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200612/internet_explorer_and_the_css_box_model/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes our red headed step child, in my experience does not resolve well with attributes. Instead do something like

```
.input {/*your styles*/}
```

Not only will it be browser adaptable but with a css reset you will find it browser persistent as well.